# How to get count of multiple column using sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
   My table like
   ---------------
      trtm       t_date          id_no  certno1   certno2  certno3  certno4  certno5  certno6 certno7 certno8 certno9  certno10 
       TM       15/02/2002       A12      2158
       TM       15/02/2010       A13      8181     8182     8183     8184     8185     8186     8187     8188      8189     8190
       TM       15/02/2010       A14      19138
      -------------------
```

I need to take count of id_no and certno from 1 to 10

```
   my query is
   ----------
  select count(id_no) as total_id,count(CONCAT(certno1, certno2, certno3,certno4,certno5,certno6,certno7,certno8,certno9,certno10)) as certificate from table where trtm='TM'
  ----------
  my output is:
   ---------
   total_id      certificate
       3             3
  -------------------------
```

but i need the count of certificate where the values are there is 3 but i need is 12

```
  ------------ 
  output needs:
  -----------
  total_id      certificate
       3             12
  -------------
```

i am getting only the count in both total_id and certificate.so, please help me if anybody knows.

Comment: See normalisation

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the "empty" certX fields are nulls, you'd need something like this:

```
SELECT (cert1 is not null) + (cert2 is not null) + ... (cert10 is not null)
```

Each `is not null` test will return a boolean true/false, which will be typecast to integers by mysql, and converted into a basic `1+1+0+1+....`-type addition operation.

Answer (score 1):

Count separately and then `SUM` it:

```
SELECT 
    count(id_no) as total_id,
    (count(certno1) +
        count(certno2) +
        count(certno3) +
        count(certno4) +
        count(certno5) +
        count(certno6) +
        count(certno7) +
        count(certno8) +
        count(certno9) +
        count(certno10)) as certificate 
FROM table 
WHERE trtm='TM';
```

Comment: as i know, `sum` takes one argument..you are passing in multiple arguments here.. use `+` to add the counts instead.

Comment: Thank you Shaharyar

Comment: @sukumarK.G Accept the answer if it helped you solving the problem.